# How to create average distribution of nested group by data in pandas?

Tags: python, group-by, nested, distribution, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, df1, I am trying to extract and average distributions from:

```
   ID  site  timestamp  tracking_value
0  03  AMF 2018-01-01          1.0
1  08  AMF 2018-01-01          1.0
2  09  AMF 2018-01-01          1.0
3  14  ARR 2018-01-01          0.0
4  16  ARR 2018-01-01          0.0
5  21  AZM 2018-01-01          0.0
6  22  BII 2018-01-01          0.0
7  23  ARR 2018-01-01          0.0
8  26  AZM 2018-01-01          1.0
9  27  AMF 2018-01-01          1.0
                 ...
                 ...
```

For each ID group, for each site for that ID group, I want to get the distribution of lengths of consecutive tracking values. Then I want to average those site distributions for the ID, to produce the distribution of lengths of time that tracking_value was not a dropout (0.0).

I have this working without the second group by (group by site), for only one ID:

```
import more_itertools as mit
import seaborn as sns
id = '03'
# Get the tracking_value data for ID 03
data = df1[df1['ID'] == id]['tracking_value']
# Get the "run length" for each value in data
distribution_of_run_lengths = list(mit.run_length.encode(data))
# Keep the distribution of run lengths for only the 0.0 values
distribution_of_run_lengths_for_zero = [x[1] for x in disn if x[0] == 0.0]
# Plot the counts of run_lengths for each run_length value
sns.countplot(distribution_of_run_lengths_for_zero )
```

Which is fine for only one ID. Plot shows the number of times (yaxis) we had the dropout lengths (xaxis) for the ID 03:
[image: Dropout lengths for ID 03]

However I need to extend this as mentioned above and have started by grouping by ID then site, but have been stuck on where to go from there:

```
data = df1.groupby(['ID','site'])['tracking_value']
```

Any suggestions on a way forward would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you're looking for. Setup:

```
dates = np.repeat(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31'), 4)
np.random.seed(100)
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': dates,
    'site': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']*(dates.shape[0]//4),
    'id': [1, 2, 1, 2]*(dates.shape[0]//4),
    'tracking_val': np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[0.4, 0.6], size=dates.shape)
})
```

Now perform the (many) `groupby` aggregations necessary to get what you want:

```
run_length_dict = {} # place to hold results
for name, group in test_df.groupby(['site', 'id']):
    # Number all consecutive runs of 1 or 0
    runs = group['tracking_val'].ne(group['tracking_val'].shift()) \
                                .cumsum() \
                                .rename(columns={'tracking_val': 'run_number'})
    # Group each run by its number *and* the tracking value, then find the length of that run
    run_lengths = runs.groupby([runs, group['tracking_val']]).agg('size')
    # One final groupby (this time, on the tracking_val/level=1) to get the count of lengths
    # and push it into the dict with the name of the original group -  ("site", "id") tuple
    run_length_dict[name]  = run_lengths.groupby(level=1).value_counts()
```

Result:

```
{('A', 1): tracking_val   
 0             1    2
               2    1
               3    1
               4    1
               5    1
 1             1    3
               2    3
               6    1
 dtype: int64, ('A', 2): tracking_val   
 0             1    5
               2    2
               3    1
               4    1
 1             1    6
               2    1
               3    1
               4    1
 dtype: int64, ('B', 1): tracking_val   
 0             1    6
               2    2
 1             2    4
               1    2
               4    2
               3    1
 dtype: int64, ('B', 2): tracking_val   
 0             1    5
               2    2
               3    2
 1             1    5
               2    2
               3    1
               4    1
 dtype: int64}
```